# Update table data using loop postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have 2 tables, `stock` and `store`

stock:

```
|-----------------|                      
|  Id | store_id  |
|-----|-----------|                        
|   1 |           |                                 
|-----|-----------|
|   2 |           |  
|-----|-----------|                                           
|   3 |           |  
|-----|-----------|                              
|   4 |           |                                                             
|-----|-----------|
```

store:

```
|-----------------|
|  Id | name      |
|-----|-----------|
|   21|   aaaa    |  
|-----|-----------|
|   12|    bbbb   |  
|-----|-----------|
```

I need to loop over store table and and put its id in stock table's store_id column,
the result should be:

```
|-----------------|                      
|  Id | store_id  |
|-----|-----------|                        
|   1 |    21     |                                 
|-----|-----------|
|   2 |    12     |  
|-----|-----------|                                           
|   3 |    21     |  
|-----|-----------|                              
|   4 |    12     |                                                             
|-----|-----------|
```

I have tried some example like [Postgresql Update inside For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507477/postgresql-update-inside-for-loop)

But didn't get a solution... plz help

Comment: You don't want to use a loop.  A loop is almost always the wrong solution in SQL.  How are you determining which store_id goes with each id in stock?

Comment: it is like 21 will go first and then 12 will go and so on.

Comment: You need to add *all* products to *all* stores? Cross Join.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar When saying "first", do you mean ordered by stock `id`? Or something else? By "and so on", you mean alternatingly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit skeptical that this is what you actually want, but from what you describe, it seems like this is the answer:

```
UPDATE STOCK SET store_id = (CASE WHEN id%2=1 THEN 21 ELSE 12 END);
```